# How to automatically open a new/unvisited link on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click, greasemonkey

I am using firefox and continuously refreshing a webpage to check if a new link/post has came on the webpage. Currently I am using reload every and refreshing a webpage and when a new link comes I click on that but I need to automate this task. 
While searching on google I have found that I can use Greasemonkey to achieve this. Don't know how exactly to do this. What I have thought is I will make already present links to webpage as  visited i.e. click on already present links, then start reload every and make greasemonkey click on unvisited links. I am not sure if this can be achieved.
Need your suggestions on this or if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: Do you have any programming experience at all? Have you ever coded in JavaScript? If not, I do have a suggestion: learn JavaScript, try to solve this problem, and when you get stuck, post again.

Comment: Yes I have programming experience but never worked on javascript. Please help just give me a hint on this and I will try to research more I just want to click on unvisited links

Comment: Link to the page in question.  What do the links look like?  By "click on unvisited links", do you want them in a new tab/window?  More than one at a time?

Comment: Yes in a new tab. The webpage is more of like a forum and whenever a new post comes in (which is obviously unvisited as it is new) I want to open it in anew tab

Comment: No I dont want to open multiple link just one link. Can't provide link to the webpage as it requires login :( but it is more of like forum where I want to click on a new thread as soon as it is added to the webpage

Comment: Guyz just to clarify stuff here by unvisited link I mean the links not opened by me just by me so that way I want to open the links that I have not opened. I will click the links already present on the web page so that the new links are taken as unvisited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript can no longer tell if a link was visited<sup>1</sup>, so you (your script) will have to track this separately.  So the task breaks down to:

1. Monitor the page for new links.
2. Track whether the links have been "clicked".  This will probably have to use persistent storage, depending on **details that the question didn't provide**.
3. "Click" or follow the links.  In a new tab/window or the same window?

Each one of these items is a question by itself.  And specific details of the page, and what you are trying to do make a huge difference in practice.

I *might* write a general answer later, but I recommend that you ask questions on each part -- [break the task into palatable chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Be exact on what you are trying to accomplish, and **link to the target page.**  If you cannot link for some reason, save the page to a file and post that file at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/), then link to that.

---

<sup>1</sup> Such a capability is considered a security hole.

Comment: While searching I came upon this link http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/greasemonkey/2005-November/006821.html which allows me to differentiate between visited and unvisited link

Comment: Cant provide link to the webpage as it requires login :( but it is more of like forum where I want to click on a new thread as soon as it is added to the webpage

Comment: Guyz just to clarify stuff here by unvisited link I mean the links not opened by me just by me so that way I want to open the links that I have not opened. I will click the links already present on the web page so that the new links are taken as unvisited

Comment: Re: `"While searching I came upon this link"`... No, it will not. Try it and see.  That security hole was closed in later editions of the major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a greasemonkey script that reloads the window after 30 seconds. In your script, you would put:

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(window.location.reload, 30000);
}
```

Assuming that greasemonkey will let you execute javascript

Comment: Should that be `setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 30000);`?

Comment: There was a bug in my code. Instead of setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 30000); it should be setTimeout(window.location.reload, 30000);. You don't need the quotes either. You are passing the function itself as an argument. By doing that, you avoid an internal call to eval()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how to click on the new links that come on webpage?